# Recurrence proof problem

Tags: recurrence-relations

I need to show that $a_n= 2^n + a_{n-2}$ for $n$ is greater than or equal to $2$. Prior to that we are told that recursively define $a_0 = 1,\, a_1 = 3, a_2 = 5,\, $ and $ a_n = 3a_{n-2} + 2a_{n-3}$ for $n$ is greater than or equal to $3$.

I tried writing out a characteristic equation and got the following: $x^3 - 3x - 2 = 0$, for which the solutions I got were $x = -1, 2$. I tried solving for constants, but I ended up getting $4\over3$ and $-1\over3$. If I could get some guidance as to how to approach the problem and whether I was on the right track, I would greatly appreciate it.

The third solution that I got seemed to be zero. I did the following math:

$a_0 = 1 = C_1 + C_3\\a_1 = 3 = -C_1 - C_2 + 2C_3\\a_2 = 5 = C_1 + 2C_2 + 4C_3$

Comment: You should have gotten one more solution since that's a cubic.  If there is a multiplicity then you need need to try $a_n = Ar^n + Bnr^n$.

Comment: @Jared I made an edit in the question to show the math I did. I wasn't sure what you meant when you said if there's a multiplicity.

Comment: By "a multiplicity" he means *a root with multiplicity greater than one* such as is the case with the characteristic polynomial $(x-2)^3=0$.  Note: $x^3-3x-2 =(x-2)(x+1)^2$, so the root $-1$ has multiplicity two and should appear twice in the closed form solution.  You should expect then that it will be of the form $a_n=c_1(-1)^n + c_2n(-1)^n + c_3(2)^n$

Comment: Your system of equations seems to suggest that you were already aware of this (*though it wasn't well stated if that is the case*), but would seem to contain an error in the second line, it should read instead $a_1=3=-c_1\color{red}{-}c_2 + 2c_3$

Comment: I did unfortunately type the second line in wrong in that I messed up with the second sign. I'm having issues moving on from this point. I tried doing some manipulations of the equations, but can't seem to find any solutions for any of the c values.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: I suggest a very different approach. You know that

$$a_n=3a_{n-2}+2a_{n-3}\;,$$

and you want to show that

$$a_n=2^n+a_{n-2}\;.\tag{0}$$

In order for this to be true, it must be the case that

$$2^n=a_n-a_{n-2}=2(a_{n-2}+a_{n-3})$$

and hence that $a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}=2^{n-1}$ for each $n\ge 3$ or, equivalently, that

$$a_n+a_{n-1}=2^{n+1}\tag{1}$$

for each $n\ge 1$. Conversely, if you knew that $(1)$ was true for all $n\ge 0$, you could easily combine it with the original recurrence to deduce $(0)$. Try to prove $(1)$ by induction on $n$. Your induction hypothesis should be that $(1)$ holds for $n=k$ and $n=k-1$, say, and you’ll use it and the original recurrence to prove that $(1)$ holds for $n=k+1$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. As for the actual induction, with n = k +1, would I simply plug that into (1), and then show that it works for a value of k greater than or equal to 1? Or would I need to try to manipulate the left side of the equation such that I am able to get it to be equal to the right side? Thanks.

Comment: @Matt: The latter. Try to manipulate $a_{k+1}+a_k$ to get $2^{k+2}$; your first step should be to use the original recurrence to get rid of $a_{k+1}$. Then you’ll use both induction hypotheses, followed by a little algebra.